# Copy single row range to array then pass ByRef to function VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've been struggling with this code here (probably very simple mistake), would anyone mind pointing out where my issues are? My overall goal is to allow this subroutine to accept a range of variable size, however I can't seem to get it to work for a fixed size.

If I manually allocate the array, things work as expected but when I allocate with a range that's where things go wrong. The output comes back untouched, which leads me to believe that I'm not doing something correctly with the allocation. Also I'm getting errors when I try to pass ws.UsedRange as oppose to a fixed range.

```
Private Sub InsertionSort(ByRef a(), ByVal lo0 As Long, ByVal hi0 As Long)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, v As Long

    For i = lo0 + 1 To hi0
        v = a(i)
        j = i
        Do While j > lo0
            If Not a(j - 1) > v Then Exit Do
            a(j) = a(j - 1)
            j = j - 1
        Loop
        a(j) = v
    Next i
End Sub

Sub runSort()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Dim myArr() As Variant
    Dim rangeUse As Range

    With ws.Range("D17:K17")
        ReDim myArr(1 To 1, 1 To ws.Range("D17:K17").Columns.Count)
        myArr = ws.Range("D17:K17").Value
    End With

    Call InsertionSort(myArr, LBound(myArr), UBound(myArr))
    Range("D19:K19") = myArr
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated! TIA

Comment: when assigning a range to an array, you will always get a 2 dimensional array (even if there is only 1 column/row of data). I would check your error handling - if it's not returning an error, or failing with a "debug" box, then something is not letting you see the errors in your code

Comment: *`allow this subroutine to accept a range of variable size`* what do you mean?

Comment: @SeanChesire - there's no error returned all I get is an unsorted array as output

Comment: @mehow - rather than passing ws.Range("D17:K17"), I would like to just select the range with my cursor, run the sub routine and get the output.

Comment: Change `Dim myArr() As Variant` to `Dim myArr As Variant`. As it stands, you are creating an array of `Variants`. What you want is one `Variant` to hold an array. This [Chip Pearson page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm) might help.

Comment: @DougGlancy I believe that will cause a type mismatch error with the insertionsort sub, no?

Comment: That's right. You'd need to change the declaration, but the rest might work. That's my quick take on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So considerating you only want to sort your 2-dimensional array row by row, this might be a useful starting point. You can always change `With ws.Range("A2:A3")` to `With Selection`. If you do so, you have the Range you selected with your cursor.

```
With ws.Range("A2:A3")
    myArr = .Value
    For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
        ReDim tmpArr(1 To .Columns.Count)
        For j = 1 To .Columns.Count
            tmpArr(j) = myArr(i, j)
        Next j

        Call InsertionSort(tmpArr, 1, .Columns.Count)

        For j = 1 To .Columns.Count
            myArr(i, j) = tmpArr(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    .Offset(RowOffset:=10) = myArr
End With
```

**Detailed Description**

You don't have to `redim myArray` because if you set it to a range, it automatically scales.

`tmpArr` is each row of your range. If you select your range with the cursor some rows might be shorter or longer than others, thats why we redim that one. **Edit** This doesn't work just yet, because `.Columns.Count` refers to the whole range, not just the row. If you have different column counts then you'd have to change that.

```
For j = 1 To .Columns.Count
    tmpArr(j) = myArr(i, j)
Next j
```

Unfortunately we cannot use `tmpArr = myArr(i)` because only one dimension of a multidimensional array cannot be accessed like this in VBA.

`Call InsertionSort(tmpArr, 1, .Columns.Count)` calles your Insertion Sort algorithm and sorts one row at a time.

After `tmpArray` got sorted, we have to set `myArray(i)` to the new values with the same loop we already used:

```
For j = 1 To .Columns.Count
    myArr(i, j) = tmpArr(j)
Next j
```

Now we sorted all the rows in our Range, now we can put it back on the sheet, 10 rows beneath the first row of the specified range with `.Offset(RowOffset:=10) = myArr`

I hope that this helps you! While testing I saw that you might have a little bug in your InsertionSort algorithm. If the first value is the smalles, it just blindly gets copied into all the other fields of the array :)